# PHP PDO DB Function returns 1 instead of value requested

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am bit confused as when try the code below I receive the desired result.

```
   include_once('config.class.php');
   $db = Core::getInstance();     
   $whr = 'test@nannex.com';

  $inv = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE email=:whr");
  $inv->execute(array(":whr"=>$whr));
  $row = $inv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row['email'];
    echo $row['full_name'];
```

However, when I run the following code it returns 1 not the desired result.

```
     include_once('config.class.php');
     $db = Core::getInstance();     
     $whr = 'test@nannex.com';    

     function fetchUser($whr){  
    $db = Core::getInstance();              
    $inv = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE :whr");
            $inv->execute(array(':whr'=>$whr)); 
    $res = $inv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $res;
}
    $row = fetchUser("email = '".$whr."' "); 
    echo $row['email'];
    echo $row['full_name'];
```

Comment: I just edited the code to reflect this $row = fetchUser("email = '".$whr."' "); and I received 1 again.

Comment: You can only bind variables, not statements like `a = b`.

Comment: The reason you can only bind variables and not statements is that the whole point of bound variables is that you compile the SQL statement, and it is only missing the values.  The executable part of the statement does not change.  This is both a performance benefit, because the DB does not have recompile the statement every time, and removes a security hole because no matter how dirty your data is, it doesn't modify the code to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE :whr
```

When expanded:

```
SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE 'email = \'test@nannex.com\''
```

The expression `email = \'test@nannex.com\'` will be evaluated by MySQL as a boolean and is always truthy, so it will return all rows in `ruj_users`.

If you want custom conditions, you can do something like this:

```
function fetchUser(array $conditions)
{
    // ...
    $sql = 'SELECT * FORM ruj_users WHERE';
    $params = array();
    foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $column)) {
            $sql .= "`$column` = ?";
            $params[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $inv = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $inv->execute(array_values($params));
    // ...
}

fetchUser(array(
    'email' => 'test@nannex.com',
    'status' => 23,
));
```

Comment: How do I modify the code so that I can always pass variable into the function to return a column result?

Comment: @ClaudeGrecea Added an example of how to add extra conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround!

Comment: Since I now have two conditions and I wanted to separate them by an 'AND' like so $column = ? AND $column = ? . How would I accomplish this within the code that I have? Do I use implode or do i add a `sql .=` somewhere? Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query in the function:

```
$inv = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE :whr");
```

Should be:

```
$inv = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ruj_users WHERE email=:whr");
```

**Edit:** If you want to pass column names as well, you would have to add another variable to your function:

```
function fetchUser($column, $value) {
```

Note that only the value can be bound in a prepared statement, the column variable you would have to check against a white-list to avoid sql injection and hard-code in the query, like `... WHERE $column = :whr ...`

Comment: I changed to $row = fetchUser("email = '".$whr."' "); and it still returned 1. Additionally, I tried your answer and returned 1 also.

Comment: @Claude Grecea See my comment below your question.

Comment: Not sure, but I think we misunderstood OP's purpose; they want to specify the WHERE condition via a function argument.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like someone came in and serial downvoted the question and all the answers =p